# ontouchListener code not running?

Tags: android

I have a toggleButton that should run code when I press it and more when I let go. However it's not working like that at all, just like a  toggle button normally does, I press it and it changes state, it doesn't call the touchlistener code at all.
In my in_call_card.xml I have:

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/PTT_button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
            android:text="@string/ptt5" 
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textOn="Push To Talk On"
            android:textOff="Push To Talk Off"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_lightblue_glossy"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />
```

in onCreate I have setContent to in_card_main.xml so I have to inflate the layout to use the button in in_call_card.xml. Here is my code, but it never runs when i am pressing the button:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View otherLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.in_call_card, null);
        final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) otherLayout.findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5);
        toggle.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "woot7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //may need to change to loop and send all ids.
                int callId = 0;
              for (SipCallSession callInfo : callsInfo) {
                  callId = callInfo.getCallId();
                  Log.e(TAG, ""+callInfo.getCallId());

              }

              final int id= callId;

                   switch(event.getAction()) {


                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                          toggle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                         toggle.setChecked(true);
                          OnDtmf(0, 17, 10);
                          OnDtmf(0, 16, 9);
                          OnDtmf(id, 17, 10);
                          OnDtmf(id, 16, 9);
                         break;
                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                           //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "woot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         //release
                         toggle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                         toggle.setChecked(false);
                         OnDtmf(0, 18, 11); 
                      OnDtmf(0, 18, 11);
                         OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);    
                      OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);       
                         break;
                   }
                   return false;
            }
        });
```

EDIT:

in_call_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    Copyright (C) 2010 Regis Montoya (aka r3gis - www.r3gis.fr) 

    This file is part of CSipSimple.
    CSipSimple is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.
    If you own a pjsip commercial license you can also redistribute it
    and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License
    as an android library.

    CSipSimple is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with CSipSimple.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
-->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/dropZones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout="@layout/in_call_drop_zones" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inCallContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!--
                Can we do better than using two linear layouts here?
                The problem is that RelativeLayout doesn't allow to use weight and
                plays bad with hidden childs and above/below only support one id
            -->
            <!-- Grid for active calls -->

            <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallInfoGrid
                android:id="@+id/activeCallsGrid"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingBottom="4dip"
                android:paddingTop="4dip"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

            <!-- Grid for held calls -->

            <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallInfoGrid
                android:id="@+id/heldCallsGrid"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/in_call_held_background"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Answer slider/buttons -->

        <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.locker.InCallAnswerControls
            android:id="@+id/inCallAnswerControls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- Wraps split action bar manually managed -->

        <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallControls
            android:id="@+id/inCallControls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/incall_bottom_bar_bg" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.locker.ScreenLocker
        android:id="@+id/lockerOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8000"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <!--
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lockerIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginBottom="70dip"
            android:text="@string/touch_lock" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/dialpad_lock" />
        -->
    </com.csipsimple.ui.incall.locker.ScreenLocker>

       <!--   <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/PTT_button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:text="@string/ptt3" 
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textOn="Push To Talk On"
            android:textOff="Push To Talk Off"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_lightblue_glossy"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />   -->   

</RelativeLayout>
```

in_call_card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/call_card_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="2dip"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw" >

    <com.csipsimple.widgets.MaxScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/call_action_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture_180_holo_light" /> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_name_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#9e808080"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
  <!--     
            <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >



        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
       --> 

        <com.csipsimple.widgets.MarqueeTextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name_display_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <com.csipsimple.widgets.MarqueeTextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name_sip_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name_display_name"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/elapsedTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/call_status_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:background="#c818617b"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="@string/call_state_calling"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/call_secure_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/call_status_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:background="#c8d4aa00" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/call_secure_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty_description"
            android:src="@drawable/stat_sys_vp_phone_call" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/call_secure_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/call_secure_icon"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/call_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/end_call_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout


        android:id="@+id/end_call_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/end_call_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!--   android:onClick="pushtotalk3" -->
         <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/PTT_button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:text="@string/ptt5" 
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textOn="Push To Talk On"
            android:textOff="Push To Talk Off"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_lightblue_glossy"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />      

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/endButton"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:contentDescription="@string/done"
            android:minHeight="64dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_end_call" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't call the listener?

Comment: Logcat? Does the app FC or gives you an error? Did you try putting a Log or a Toast to see if it gets to the function?

Comment: @Simon nothing is logged, there is no toast and so on.

Comment: @SiKni8 no error, no log, no toast, all that happens is the button toggles on and off

Comment: for instance, if I comment out the listener completely, there is no change in functionality at all!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setContentView(int)` you have to use `findViewById(int)` because the activity inflates the XML for you.

For the moment you are putting a listener on a button which is not displayed, because you get it from the layout *you* have inflated, but not from the one the activity hold.

2 solutions :

- Add the missing ending `setContentView(otherLayout)` call to **tell your activity to display the layout you have inflated**
- Use `setContentView(R.layout.in_call_card)` and then retrieve the view by using only `findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5);` to **tell you activity to display the layout 'in_call_card' before asking it to search for the view with the id 'R.id.PTT_button5' in its hierarchy**

Comment: Very confusing for me. I tried setContentView(otherLayout) and the button gets displayed - looks different and works but the rest of the layout is all broken now. What confuses is me is how the button was displayed in the first place, was it that I inflated it but did not attach it to anything? I cant figure out how to just have the main layout with this one button added and working also. I need elements from both xml files to be displayed and working.

Comment: @Paul You can inflate a layout whithout displaying it. When you use `setContentView(int)` you tell your activity to inflate the XML and to display it. So then when you will use `myactivity.findViewById(int)` it will search in the inflated views it is holding. But when you inflate an XML resource by yourself, if you forget to set it as your content view, you will work with views that are **not displayed**. It seems that you were in this case. Then you have 2 solutions (e.g. my answer).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it nearly works, I mean if I do as you suggest the button gets displayed and works but everything else in the view does not work and is displayed incorrectly. If I setContentView bac to  in_call_main then everything is displayed but the button does not work. So setting either of them does not seem to be the solution for me due to the weird layout this program uses. How come if I can see the button in the first place, if I am not setting the content right? the button is on the screen, so why cant i set a listener for it? According to you the button should not be seen

Comment: How do you set the layout as the content view so it is correctly displayed (whether the button works or not) ?

Comment: I do this: setContentView(R.layout.in_call_main); (it was already in the program im editing) With this I can see everything perfectly, with our without inflating anything. The toggle button goes on and off but does nothing. So I don't know how to make it actually run code, seeing as the button xml is in a different file. I'm not sure how he is making the other buttons work, as they are also in this other xmlfile. Here is the java file: https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/src/com/csipsimple/ui/incall/InCallActivity.java?r=2231

Comment: Ok so don't inflate anything, remove useless additionnal code, and just retrieve the displayed button using `findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5)` and then register your listener. It should do the job.

Comment: I think that is what I originally tried, however I think that was a nullpointerexception due to the button not being in the contentview that I set? Can i findviewbyid of something without setcontent of the xml file that it is in?

Comment: Yes you can on an inflated layout, but you've already tried that. If you get a NPE it means that your are displaying the wrong layout OR you are giving `findViewById(int)` the wrong id. Just try again and check that.

Comment: I tried this findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5).setOnTouchListener(this); and it gives NPE because setContentView is not for that xml file perhaps?

Comment: If you get an NPE it means the displayed layout is not the one you think it is, or your button has another id. Check you are setting the correct layout as the content view and also check if it has a view with ID `R.id.PTT_button5` in its hierarchy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40178/discussion-between-minde-and-paul)

Answer (score 0):

It's not your listener. Your listener works fine, with `ToggleButton` or any other kind of view. With the `return false` at the end, your `onTouchListener` should get called and an `onClickListener`- if one exists - gets called.

**The reason why you get nothing when you press the button is**, that the button is not on your screen. You inflate it in your code, but without a parent and I cant see any code, that actually adds the inflated `ToggleButton` to any layout. So, whatever you have on your screen that you press, it's not that button your `onTouchListener` listens.

I recommend to make the `ToggleButton`part of you `layout` or - depending on your App Design - create a new `Layout` and `Activity` for this.

**EDIT** According to the posted layouts.

What I understand is, that you have two full layouts: `in_card_main.xml` and `in_call_card.xml` but only one `Activity`. Is that right? If yes, the solution is to have one Activity for each layout and call the Activities with `startActivity()`.

Comment: I dont really understand how I can see a button before I inflate it, and after I inflate it it is not attached, how can I jsut add it to the current screen. I mean if it's showing on the screen, before I even call the inflation, surely there should be a way for it to do something. I thought it was part of the layout, seeing as it is on the screen. I didnt think I had to inflate anything but I get a nullpointer if I dont.

Comment: The button you see on the screen is not the button you inflate in your code. What you have on the screen must be in your layout. Can you post us the layout of `in_card_main.xml` (not `in_call_card.xml` which we have already)? Basically I think you have a button in the main layout that should be the one that your touch listener should be registered for. But lets have a look at your main layout first. Ah, there it is, thanks. Let's see...

Comment: there is only one activity yes, if I made another activity what woulld even go in it though? I am editing code, I didn't write this, what I don't follow is how they have two layouts, and one activity yet all their buttons work fine and mine does not. Surely if the button appears on the screen from these layouts there is a way to hook it up to be actually working. If I make another activity, I'm not sure what I'm doing in it. DO I just have the listener in an onCreate?